# How to insert table.tex into my latex document

Tags: tables, syntax

I am trying to figure out how to insert the table I generated in Stata in tex format into my latex document. Currently, I get errors when I copy-paste and after I did modifications to the code. Below is exactly the content of the exported tex file.

I appreciate your help; thank you!

```
\begin{table} \begin{tabular}{l|cc|cc|cc}
                    $&$        mod1  $&$        mod2  $&$        mod3  \\
                    $&$        b/se  $&$        b/se  $&$        b/se  \\
yrsinG              $&$      -0.002  $&$      -0.000  $&$       0.006  \\
                    $&$     (0.003)  $&$     (0.003)  $&$     (0.004)  \\
ageatentry          $&$       0.011^{**}$&$       0.011^{**}$&$       0.017^{**}\\
                    $&$     (0.002)  $&$     (0.002)  $&$     (0.003)  \\
school_vG           $&$      -0.063  $&$      -0.093  $&$      -0.052  \\
                    $&$     (0.096)  $&$     (0.099)  $&$     (0.132)  \\
[1] inadequately    $&$       0.000  $&$       0.000  $&$       0.000  \\
                    $&$         (.)  $&$         (.)  $&$         (.)  \\
[2] general elemantary$&$       0.043  $&$       0.041  $&$       0.122  \\
                    $&$     (0.063)  $&$     (0.064)  $&$     (0.087)  \\
[3] middle vocational$&$      -0.021  $&$      -0.017  $&$       0.038  \\
                    $&$     (0.084)  $&$     (0.086)  $&$     (0.123)  \\
[4] vocational ^{+} Abi$&$       0.009  $&$       0.026  $&$       0.061  \\
                    $&$     (0.116)  $&$     (0.119)  $&$     (0.170)  \\
[5] higher vocational$&$       0.189  $&$      -0.052  $&$       0.398  \\
                    $&$     (0.258)  $&$     (0.249)  $&$     (0.419)  \\
[6] higher education$&$       0.115  $&$       0.111  $&$       0.261  \\
                    $&$     (0.171)  $&$     (0.173)  $&$     (0.234)  \\
yrschl              $&$      -0.001  $&$       0.003  $&$      -0.011  \\
                    $&$     (0.028)  $&$     (0.028)  $&$     (0.041)  \\
male                $&$      -0.050  $&$      -0.050  $&$      -0.082  \\
                    $&$     (0.032)  $&$     (0.032)  $&$     (0.043)  \\
Number of Children in HH$&$      -0.066^{**}$&$      -0.066^{**}$&$      -0.063^{**}\\
                    $&$     (0.012)  $&$     (0.012)  $&$     (0.017)  \\
spouse_abroad       $&$       0.155^{**}$&$       0.157^{**}$&$       0.184^{+} \\
                    $&$     (0.057)  $&$     (0.058)  $&$     (0.073)  \\
parent_abroad       $&$       0.106  $&$       0.094  $&$       0.194^{+} \\
                    $&$     (0.067)  $&$     (0.068)  $&$     (0.085)  \\
child_abroad        $&$       0.049  $&$       0.029  $&$      -0.007  \\
                    $&$     (0.039)  $&$     (0.040)  $&$     (0.053)  \\
disability          $&$      -0.073  $&$      -0.079  $&$      -0.079  \\
                    $&$     (0.062)  $&$     (0.063)  $&$     (0.086)  \\
[1] Sehr gut        $&$      -0.092  $&$      -0.069  $&$      -0.065  \\
                    $&$     (0.059)  $&$     (0.062)  $&$     (0.087)  \\
[2] Gut             $&$      -0.009  $&$      -0.004  $&$       0.031  \\
                    $&$     (0.033)  $&$     (0.034)  $&$     (0.046)  \\
[3] Es geht         $&$       0.000  $&$       0.000  $&$       0.000  \\
                    $&$         (.)  $&$         (.)  $&$         (.)  \\
[4] Eher schlecht   $&$      -0.015  $&$      -0.022  $&$       0.010  \\
                    $&$     (0.033)  $&$     (0.033)  $&$     (0.043)  \\
[5] Gar nicht       $&$      -0.146^{**}$&$      -0.145^{**}$&$      -0.142^{+} \\
                    $&$     (0.050)  $&$     (0.051)  $&$     (0.069)  \\
wfulltime           $&$       0.015  $&$       0.035  $&$       0.057  \\
                    $&$     (0.066)  $&$     (0.067)  $&$     (0.084)  \\
inactive            $&$       0.006  $&$       0.047  $&$       0.004  \\
                    $&$     (0.067)  $&$     (0.068)  $&$     (0.086)  \\
unemployed          $&$       0.051  $&$       0.071  $&$      -0.094  \\
                    $&$     (0.086)  $&$     (0.087)  $&$     (0.113)  \\
unemployed_past     $&$       0.036  $&$       0.026  $&$       0.048  \\
                    $&$     (0.032)  $&$     (0.033)  $&$     (0.042)  \\
[2] B1 Tuerkischer HV$&$      -0.197^{**}$&$      -0.218^{**}$&$      -0.326^{**}\\
                    $&$     (0.046)  $&$     (0.047)  $&$     (0.063)  \\
[3] B2 Jugoslawischer HV$&$      -0.341^{**}$&$      -0.344^{**}$&$      -0.362^{**}\\
                    $&$     (0.044)  $&$     (0.046)  $&$     (0.065)  \\
[4] B3 Griechischer HV$&$      -0.088  $&$      -0.116^{+} $&$      -0.156^{+} \\
                    $&$     (0.050)  $&$     (0.051)  $&$     (0.069)  \\
[5] B4 Italienischer HV$&$      -0.115^{+} $&$      -0.120^{+} $&$      -0.068  \\
                    $&$     (0.049)  $&$     (0.051)  $&$     (0.072)  \\
[6] B5 Spanischer HV$&$       0.000  $&$       0.000  $&$       0.000  \\
                    $&$         (.)  $&$         (.)  $&$         (.)  \\
[1] Schleswig-Holstein       1$&$      -0.279^{**}$&$       0.000  $&$       0.000  \\
                    $&$     (0.072)  $&$         (.)  $&$         (.)  \\
[2] Hamburg                  2$&$       0.044  $&$       0.041  $&$       0.082  \\
                    $&$     (0.078)  $&$     (0.080)  $&$     (0.100)  \\
[3] Lower Saxony             3$&$      -0.058  $&$      -0.089  $&$      -0.245^{**}\\
                    $&$     (0.054)  $&$     (0.053)  $&$     (0.063)  \\
[4] Bremen                   4$&$       0.172  $&$       0.202  $&$       0.280  \\
                    $&$     (0.120)  $&$     (0.122)  $&$     (0.185)  \\
[5] North-Rhine-Westfalia    5$&$       0.000  $&$       0.000  $&$       0.000  \\
                    $&$         (.)  $&$         (.)  $&$         (.)  \\
[6] Hessen                   6$&$      -0.071  $&$      -0.090^{+} $&$      -0.134^{+} \\
                    $&$     (0.040)  $&$     (0.041)  $&$     (0.053)  \\
[7] Rheinland-Pfalz          7$&$      -0.021  $&$      -0.045  $&$      -0.151  \\
                    $&$     (0.061)  $&$     (0.061)  $&$     (0.079)  \\
[8] Baden-Wuerttemberg       8$&$       0.009  $&$      -0.012  $&$      -0.079  \\
                    $&$     (0.034)  $&$     (0.035)  $&$     (0.048)  \\
[9] Bavaria                  9$&$      -0.025  $&$      -0.047  $&$       0.003  \\
                    $&$     (0.041)  $&$     (0.042)  $&$     (0.057)  \\
[11] Berlin                 11$&$      -0.108  $&$      -0.117  $&$      -0.140  \\
                    $&$     (0.071)  $&$     (0.071)  $&$     (0.102)  \\
current_satisfaction$&$      -0.003  $&$      -0.001  $&$       0.004  \\
                    $&$     (0.006)  $&$     (0.006)  $&$     (0.008)  \\
return              $&$              $&$       0.180^{**}$&$              \\
                    $&$              $&$     (0.031)  $&$              \\
logplannedstay      $&$              $&$              $&$      -0.075^{**}\\
                    $&$              $&$              $&$     (0.024)  \\
\end{tabular} \end{table}
^{+} p<0.05, ^{**} p<0.01
```

Comment: The errors are probably in the last line.

Comment: @lhf The errors are everywhere.

Comment: Shouldn't it be when I export it in Stata, it makes it almost ready to use?

Comment: estout mod1 mod2 mod3  ///
   using AcReturn_withIntended3.tex, cells(b(star fmt(%5.3f)) se(par)) ///
   starlevels( + 0.05 ** 0.01) substitute(+ ^{+} ** ^{**} ) ///
   varwidth(20) legend label delimiter("$&$" ) ///
    varlabels(_cons constant )  ///
   style(tex) replace ///
   prehead("\begin{table} \begin{tabular}{l|cc|cc|cc}") ///
   prefoot("\end{tabular} \end{table}")

Comment: I don't know Stata.  Is that code that you gave it?  Because it's the source of many of your problems.

Comment: Maybe you can consider package [`pgfplotstable`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplotstable.pdf) which reads from a text file and generates an elegant table with many options you can set.

Comment: Yes, it is how I generated the tex file from Stata. Any working example of how pgfplotstable works? ( I also have a clean copy of the table in excel sheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a quick look through a LaTeX table tutorial.  Briefly:

- columns should be separated by `&`, not `$&$`
- `{l|cc|cc|cc}` indicates that you have 7 columns, but it seems like you only have 4: `{l|c|c|c}`
- `^` needs to occur in math mode, for example, `$0.180^{**}$` (or `0.180\textsuperscript{**}`)
- Use a `\_` for a literal underscore.
- `\\` takes an optional argument in `[]`.  This causes an error if the next line begins with `[`.  In that case you need to have `\\\relax`
- Your table is two pages long.  Switch to longtable.

Some other items:

- You have many numbers in parentheses.  Does this indicate they're negative?  Then why do you also have a negative sign?
- The siunitx package provides a column type that aligns all the numbers on the decimal point.
- What are the [number] doing?  They look like citations, in which case they should be created with `\cite{reference}`.
- What does `(.)` mean?
- The booktabs package would recommend removing the vertical lines entirely.